# Are [this] and [&] in a lambda capture-list equivalent, when used inside a class?

Tags: c++, lambda

In the following example, what is the difference between using [this] in the capture-list, as opposed to using capture-by-reference [&] in the capture-list, as shown? I have tried both and they produce the same output.

```
#include <iostream>                                                          

class Test {                                                                 
public:                                                                      
   int x = 2;                                                                
   void test1(void) { std::cout << "test1" << std::endl; };                  

    void test_lambda(void) {                                                 
        auto lambda = [&] () {                                               
            std::cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << std::endl;
            this->test1();                                                         
        };                                                                   

        lambda();                                                            
    }                                                                        

protected:                                                                   
   int y = 3;                                                                

private:                                                                     
   int z = 4;                                                                
};                                                                           

int main() {                                                                 
    Test t;                                                                  
    t.test_lambda();                                                         
}
```

In the C++ Programming Language, Stroustrop says:

```
    Members are always captured by reference. That is, [this] implies that members are accessed through this rather than copied into the lambda.
```

This seems to imply that they may mean the same thing. If that's the case though, why do we need [this]?

Comment: & can be used for specific variable

Comment: Always use the least powerful capture you can use. Not only does this make local reasoning easier, but you may also avoid an error once in a while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and current object by reference if exists

Whereas using [this] will capture only the `this` pointer.

This will differ when you have automatic variables in the scope, e.g:

```
struct Test {
  void run() {
    int y = 2;

    // all automatic variables are accessible, both local and members
    auto l1 = [&](){ cout << x << " " << y << endl; };
    l1();

    // y is not accessible, x is only because it's a member
    auto l2 = [this]() { cout << this->x << endl; };
    l2();
  }

  int x = 1;
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  t.run();
}
```

**So, why do we need it?**

Allowing the capture of [this] is the same as allowing the capture of any other pointer.

Why not capture all the automatic variables all the time? There are a couple of reasons, including:

- **Encapsulation**: Sometimes, you don't want the lambda to be familiar with other values
- **Flexibility**: Sometimes, we need to copy some values and pass some of them by reference

**Note:** Capturing all automatic variables using & doesn't introduce additional performance costs, since the compiler passes only the variables we use inside the lambda.

Comment: Re: “performance”, the quote from cppreference implies that only the used variables are captured. This has no effect on performance, because if you capture less than that the compilation will fail.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to capture members is by capturing `this`:

- explicitly `[this](){ member = 42; }`
- implicitly by capture by value `[=](){ member = 42;}`
- implicitly by capture by reference `[&](){ member = 42; }`

Following are illegal

- `[&member](){ member = 42; }        // illegal`
- `[member](){ std::cout << member; } // illegal`.

Then depending of your intend to express the restriction of the capture, you might choose between being explicit or not, avoiding `reference` capture (to avoid possible dangling reference)...

Comment: I haven’t checked the standard so maybe this is a compiler extension or something, but empirically `[&member=member](){ /*...*/ }` works just fine.

Comment: @DanielH: This declares a *"named lambda member"* initialized by a variable. I won't say it is a capture of the member (in the same way, for `auto& ref = member; [&ref](){/*...*/}`), for me, it is just an initialization.

Comment: It is called a capture either way, and in this case it’s a reference to the same variable. I’m not sure what distinction you’re drawing between a capture and an initialization of a reference; is there any case where the two behave differently?

Comment: @DanielH: In `[toto=42](){std::cout << toto;}`, it seems strange to me to use the word *"capture"*. But it is mostly a vocabulary problem.

Comment: I agree, that does seem strange, but I think it’s still the technical term. What I meant was, is there a difference in behavior between `[&x=x]` and `[&x]`, when `x` is a nonmember variable name? If not, then `[&member=member]` should be equivalent to capturing `member` even if it isn’t the exact same thing.

Comment: Worth noting that in the 3rd example(`[&](){...}`), even though we use `&`, `this` is captured by value, not by reference, since `this` is a prvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` captures all variables that are in scope by reference. Consider this:

```
void test_lambda(void) {                                                 
    int dummy = 42;                    // capture dummy ?!?
    auto lambda = [&] () {             // yes                                 
        std::cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << std::endl;
        this->test1();   
        std::cout << dummy;            // ok here                                                      
    };                                                                   
    lambda();                                                            
}
```

`[this]` will not capture local variables as will `[&]`.

Comment: The question is "Since `[&]` is more powerful than `[this]`, why do we need `[this]` at all?"

Comment: @RaymondChen because you dont want to capture stuff that you dont want to capture

Comment: @RaymondChen Given that this is not in the question, and the question has not been edited, where are you getting this quote? I read it the same way tobi303 did, as asking if they are equivalent and if not how they differ.

Comment: It was the final question that summarized the issue: "If that's the case though, why do we need `[this]`?" In other words "If `[&]` is just as good as `[this]`, why do we even have `[this]`?"

Comment: @RaymondChen the last question is "If that's the case though, why do we need [this]?" where the "if thats the case" refers to `[&]` and `[this]` meaning the same thing. In my answer I tried to explain why this is wrong. Also I didnt see any "awesome"...

Comment: @RaymondChen lets simply agree on the fact that we have a different interpretation of the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `[this]` will capture only `this`, while `[&]` captures `this` *and* all local variables from the enclosing scope.

```
struct example {
  int foo;

  example() {
    int bar;

    [this]() {
      foo = {};
      bar = {}; // error: 'bar' is not captured
    }();

    [&]() {
      foo = {};
      bar = {};
    }();
  }
};
```

You might use `[this]` if your closure will be invoked outside of the enclosing scope, like a member function, as all local variables will have been destroyed.

```
struct example {
  int value = 42;

  example() {
    frobnicate = [this]() {
      std::cout << value << std::endl;
    };
  }

  std::function<void ()> frobnicate;
};

example x;
x.frobnicate();
```

You might use `[&]` if your closure will be invoked inside the enclosing scope, like a piece of local code, as the local variables will still be alive.

```
struct example {
  int value = 42;

  example() {
    int values[] = {1, 2, 3};

    std::for_each(std::begin(values), std::end(values), [&](int& v) {
      std::cout << v * value << std::endl;
    });
  }
};
```